# Failed to load the atom-emmet-css-in-js package The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object

Tags: atom-editor

I am getting a loading error when I installed the atom-emmet package in Atom. How to fix it?

[Screenshot of the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyY0a.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am not facing any problems while I compile a basic HTML file as I am a beginner. But as soon as I open atom, this pop up shows up